# Regex not working when string is too long?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, url, replace

I have a piece of code that tries to find URLs and put wrap them in `<a>` tags. It works fine for shorter strings but on longer strings it doesn't work at all. Does anyone know why?

```
function urlify(text) {
        var urlRegex = `/(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-z0-9_\-\.~]+)*(\/([a-z0-9_\-\.]*)(\?[a-z0-9+_\-\.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@/?]*)?)(\s+|$)/gi`
        return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
            return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
        });
    }
```

If I run `urlify('www.example.com is a cool website')` it returns `<a href="www.example.com">www.example.com</a> is a cool website` but if I have a string that has 5000 characters that has links it doesn't change the original string at all.

Comment: short and long strings? can you add examples to the question?

Comment: Ok I'll add examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more efficient version of the same regex:

```js
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(?:[a-z]+:\/\/)?(?:[a-z\d-]+\.)+(?:a(?:ero|rpa)|biz|co(?:m|op)|edu|gov|in(?:ternal|fo|t)|jobs|m(?:il|useum)|n(?:a(?:me|to)|et)|org|pro|travel|local|[a-z]{2})(?::\d{1,5})?(?:\/[\w.~-]+)*(?:\/[\w.-]*(?:\?[\w+.%=&;-]*)?)?(?:#[\w!$&'()*+.=~:@\/?-]*)?(?!\S)/gi
    return text.replace(urlRegex, '<a href="$&">$&</a>');
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uqL8WA/1).

The part that is difficult to optimize at this moment is the starting `(?:[a-z]+:\/\/)?(?:[a-z\d-]+\.)+`, as this allows matching pattern of unknown length anywhere in the string, and this involves quite a bit of overhead. If you wanted to only start matching from a whitespace or start of string, a `(?<!\S)` at the start would greatly speed up matching.

Comment: I'm not very good at understanding regex can you show me what the last part might look like please?

Comment: @boomcreeper11 `/(?<!\S)(?:[a-z]+:\/\/)?(?:[a-z\d-]+\.)+(?:a(?:ero|rpa)|biz|co(?:m|op)|edu|gov|in(?:ternal|fo|t)|jobs|m(?:il|useum)|n(?:a(?:me|to)|et)|org|pro|travel|local|[a-z]{2})(?::\d{1,5})?(?:\/[\w.~-]+)*(?:\/[\w.-]*(?:\?[\w+.%=&;-]*)?)?(?:#[\w!$&'()*+.=~:@\/?-]*)?(?!\S)/gi`